# How to quickly find an open file in XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface

When I open a lot (30) files in XCode simultaneously I can't switch between files effectively using   "4 fingers down" gesture - it is very hard to find needed file, especially because it hides part of their names.
Meanwhile I can't simply open the file one more time (using Cmd-O). When I do it it has no effect - XCode does not show the file on the top.

So, **how do I bring a window of an open file to the top quickly?**

Comment: I use Cmd+Shift+O to navigate around files in a project.

Comment: XCode shows all open files in the navigator area, use Cmd+0 to open/close panel

Comment: @ShamsAhmed, I open files with Cmd+O and for me it shows only one file per window.

Comment: @vcsjones, somehow it doesn't work for me. I type file name but XCode shows me void list of files.

Comment: @klm123 i usually select all in finder and open in XCode 5.

Comment: @ShamsAhmed, this will not work for me, it is hundreds of files.